# How to create array-like data-structures with object keys in PHP?

Tags: php, data-structures, dictionary

I want create arrays with object keys in PHP, i.e. something like this:

```
<?php
$keyObject   = new KeyObject;
$valueObject = new ValueObject;

$hash = array($keyObject => $valueObject);
```

However, this raises an error. Arrays may only have integer or string keys. I end up having to do something like:

```
$hash = array(
    'key'   => $keyObject,
    'value' => $valueObject);
```

This works but it's not as neat as I'd like. Is there a better way? (Perhaps something from the SPL that I'm missing...)

TIA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`SplObjectStorage`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) from the SPL as a map with object keys:

```
$map = new SplObjectStorage;
$key = new StdClass;
$value = new StdClass;
$map[$key] = $value;
```